# Leaving "Else" comments

Tags: comments, readability

Let's say I have a not-so-intuitive `if` statement in my code, but only if you're new to the codebase:

```
def set_markets(markets=None):
    """
    Will accept 'all' as markets to set all markets on.
    For individual markets, pass in a list of ints.
    """
    if markets:
        if type(markets) == list:
            markets = ','.join(map(str, markets))
        self._set_markets(markets)
```

For those of you wondering:

The existing system I'm interacting with (a database) expects a list of integers from the front end interface. This code does it from the backend, so a list of ints was chosen since it best represents what a user might feed in otherwise.

The `markets` stuff is handed down from another class, so even though it appears like it's taking place over 5 lines, it's more like ~50 lines.

My question is, would you consider this more readable? Why or why not?

```
def set_markets(markets=None):
    """
    Will accept 'all' as markets to set all markets on.
    For individual markets, pass in a list of ints.
    """
    if markets:
        if type(markets) == list:
            markets = ','.join(map(str, markets))
      # else:
          # markets are set to "all"
        self._set_markets(markets)
```

EDIT:

This code looks worse than it is because I left off a detail: if `None` is fed in for `markets` (the default parameter), then it will not modify the markets settings the database.

Here's what I have now:

```
    if markets is not None:
        if isinstance(markets, list):
            markets = ','.join(map(str, markets))
        else:
            markets = 'all'
        self._set_new_header_markets(markets)
```

Comment: Just a tip, use `isinstance(markets, list)` as the proper way to check the type of an object in Python.

Comment: Interpreting pretty much anything as "all" strikes me as very bad. I think it'd be way better to only accept "all" for that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, putting code in comments makes me assume it's dead code. It'll just be really confusing if you do that.

Secondly, the fact that you need a comment is because your code is unreadable. Try for making the code readable before adding a comment.

If you accept 'all' or a list, you should really do it like this:

```
if markets == 'all':
   self._set_markets('all')
else:
   self._set_markets(','.join(map(str, markers))
```

Then its abundantly clear what is going on and you avoid type checking, and you don't accept invalid data so long as it isn't a list.

Comment: I updated my question based on your observations.

Comment: Accepted answer for "the fact that you need a comment is because your code is unreadable".

Answer (score 2):

To me, the fact that you've formatted the `else:` to look like regular code is misleading; something more commenty seems like it'd be appropriate.

Right now it looks like the else is commented out because there is no code for that block *yet*, and the inner comment is a placeholder for code to come, which is not the case (?). I'd inline both comments, bump up the indentation on the hash and *maybe* remove the else's formatting:

```
if markets:
    if type(markets) == list:
        markets = ','.join(map(str, markets))
    # else: markets are set to "all"
    self._set_markets(markets)
```